# Is it possible to pass parameter file into AWS::CloudFormation::Stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I need to pass parameters set in in a .json file to AWS::CloudFormation::Stack resource. The file could be either in a S3 bucket or uploaded into the aws cloud shell. I could execute the aws cloudformation create-stack with parameters in a json file as follows:

`aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name VPC --template-body file://VPC.yml --parameters file://VPC-parameters.json`

My VPC-parameters.json file would look like this:

```
[
    {
        "ParameterKey": "VPCId",
        "ParameterValue": "demoVPC1ID"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "GatewayId",
        "ParameterValue": "demoGatewayID"
    }
]
```

was expecting something similar in the parameters properties of AWS::CloudFormation::Stack too.

I have tried only the aws cloudformation create-stack command which works fine with the parameter json file. But do not know how to pass this in a the AWS::CloudFormation::Stack resource

Comment: You can't do this. Consider using Ansible as a wrapper for cloudformation, this will allow you to pass through variable files and reuse the same cloudformation stack for different variable files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But do not know how to pass this in a the AWS::CloudFormation::Stack resource

Its not possible. CloudFormation does not support passing files into `AWS::CloudFormation::Stack`.